# How to calculate mean elevation in a DEM between a specific interval?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, elevation, contour

I have a DEM with different elevations between 100 m & 3828 m. 
I just want to calculate mean elevation higher than 1500 m? Can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

- Set environment setting extent=your DEM extent, snap raster = DEM,
  cell size= one for DEM.
- Use raster calculator expression:

  Con("DEM">1500,"DEM)

Right click on resulting raster, Source, scroll down to see Mean

Comment: Mark it as answered please to help others